# Google Play says my device isn't compatible with the app even though it meets required Android version

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat

I have a Hisense HS-U601 with Android 4.4.2 but when I try to download apps on Google Play that requires 4.0 and up it always says it's not compatible. For instance I can't update my Instagram app because Google Play says my device is not compatible with the app.

Answer (score 1):

From Instagram's help center:

> #### [I'm getting a "Device not compatible" error message in Google Play Store.](https://help.instagram.com/231705083624002)
>
> We're aware of an issue where some people get a "Device not compatible" error message in the Google Play Store when trying to download Instagram, even though Instagram should support the phone. Google is currently investigating this issue with Google Play Store.
>
> As a temporary workaround, Google suggests clearing Google Play Store's data from your phone and then trying to install Instagram. To do this, go to **Settings > Application Manager > All > Google Play Store > Clear data.**

Instagram is [definitely compatible](http://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/instagram-apk-latest-version-download/) with your Android version.